# jQuery 1.9 Run content rather than display content

Tags: jquery, tabs

msoliman posted this addTabs replacement function in 2014 as a replacement for the tabs("add") method found in jQuery 1.8.

```
var addTab = function (tabs, tabId, tabLabel, tabContentHtml) {
     var header = "<li><a href='#" + tabId + "'>" + tabLabel + "</a> </li>"
     tabs.find(".ui-tabs-nav").append(header);
     tabs.append("<div id='" + tabId + "'><p>" + tabContentHtml + "</p></div>");
     tabs.tabs("refresh");
};
```

Add a new tab

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
addTab($("#tabs"), "tab_id1", "Tab 1", "this is just test");
```

I need to run the content rather than display it

```
addTab($("#tabs_area"), "tab_id1", "Tab 1", myHtmlPage.html );
```

Obviously, with quotes around the filename, the filename just displays as content.
How do I cause the page to run when the new tab is added rather than display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using `$.get` to fetch the page HTML, like so:

```
var addTabFromURL = function (tabs, tabId, tabLabel, tabContentHtml) {
    $.get( tabContentHtml, function( data ) {
         var header = "<li><a href='#" + tabId + "'>" + tabLabel + "</a> </li>"
         tabs.find(".ui-tabs-nav").append(header);
         tabs.append("<div id='" + tabId + "'><p>" + data + "</p></div>");
         tabs.tabs("refresh");
    });
}
```

```
addTabFromURL($("#tabs_area"), "tab_id1", "Tab 1", "myHtmlPage.html" );
```

I've made a new function `addTabFromURL` which instead takes a relative URL as the last parameter. Using `$.get`, we can retrieve the HTML content of the passed URL, and populate our tab with it.

Of course, this method only works assuming the page you're trying to grab is inside a local subdirectory, and not an external page you don't have access to.

Comment: Wow! Thanks. I think that's just what I need.